# Gem list contains multiple dependencies to a certain gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I had `unicorn 4.5.0` and after I did `bundle update`, I observe different versions of the same gem even though I wanted to use the latest version.

```
unicorn (4.6.1, 4.5.0)
```

How do I instruct the bundler to just keep the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you cannot instruct bundler to keep only the latest version when updating. You *can* delete all the old versions of all gems in one go:

```
bundle exec gem cleanup
```

[(Reference)](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page77)

Comment: I get the following error at the end of the cleanup. Unable to uninstall bundler-1.2.3:
 Gem::InstallError: gem "bundler" is not installed
Clean Up Complete

Comment: gem cleanup seems to remove the older version, but if I do a "cap deploy" to a remote machine. How would I remove this in a automated fashion, can bundler itself do this

Comment: As I said: I don't think so. Can't you edit your deploy.rb file so that it runs `gem cleanup`?

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct bundler to just use one version by putting that version in the gem file.  Sometimes, I have had conflicts with rake, even though I did not explicitly have rake in my Gemfile, so I had to put the rake version that would be usable by all the other gems at the top of my Gemfile.

If your issue is that you used to use unicorn 4.5.0, and now it has installed unicorn 4.6.1 in you local gem source, you can tell gem to uninstall the version you no longer need.

```
gem uninstall unicorn --version 4.5.0
```

If you did a bundle --deployment and populated the vendor/bundle directory, and that is where you want to remove the gem from, then I usually just delete the gem directory, however, I think you can run bundle with --path, like the following:

```
bundle --deployment --path vendor/bundle
gem uninstall unicorn --version 4.5.0
```

When you run bundler, it remembers the settings.  I painfully discovered this regarding the --without switch.  The --path setting will tell gem to use the local vendor/bundle directory as your local gem source.  Remember to set the path back by running bundle again.

Comment: I don't want to specify a version, since on the next upgrade I would like to move to a higher version. How do I automate this.

Comment: @Sam, you can delete all old versions of all gems with `gem cleanup`. See my answer below.

Comment: You can specify the minimum version as 4.6.1 with a >= in the Gemfile.

Comment: @MarlinPierce I don't want to specify a minimum version also, this is a infrastructure software and I would like to use the latest and greatest at any point in time. Why should I waste time figuring out what the versions need to be.

Comment: @Sam, I'm not sure what your original question was, since you seemed to be concerned with the installed version not the version used by bundler.  If you have a problem with bundler *using* two versions, then you may need to.  There can be a problem where one gem in the Gemfile requires a version of a dependent gem, and then a later gem in the Gemfile requires a different one and is incompatible with the one already selected.  In that case, you have no other recourse than manipulating the version in the Gemfile.  Between Mischa and I there is a lot of information.  When to use it is up to you.